# Operation Contract on External data types

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I'm am working with the WCF and I have a composite Type. I want to make a DataContract with that complex type and its data members. Normally I would do something like this :

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

However, how do you form a data contract if you cannot modify the declaration. For example, the original class comes from a dll.

I considered making a class that wraps around the type with properties that would act as getters and setters. I could then put the contract on the wrapper class' properties but I was wonder if there was actually a way to do this.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816495/modifying-class-attribute-on-runtime

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a wrapper, IMO.