# how to make fields editable at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is it possible to apply EditableAttribute at runtime? I want to make some properties editable only when the user has some role. Unfortunately EdiatbleAttribute is sealed. I can try to apply it at runtime by reflection but maybe there's more proper way to do this. Thanks for any advices.

Best regards

Comment: Note: you can't change attributes via reflection. You *can* do this using the `System.ComponentModel`, but that only works if the caller is *asking* via `System.ComponentModel`. Unfortunately *at the property level* (rather than the type level) it is hard work to do it, and I think it is unlikely that it will achieve anything in this scenario (I suspect the caller is querying via reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *hack* available at: [How to Set Attribute Value at Runtime-- and How to Work around a Silly Bug](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-set-attribute-value-at-runtime.html)

```
private void SetPropertyGrid() 
{ 
     PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Student))["Address"];
     ReadOnlyAttribute attrib = (ReadOnlyAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];
     FieldInfo isReadOnly = attrib.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        isReadOnly.SetValue(attrib,true);

     propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Student();  
}
```

I was able to this code to change the `ReadOnly` attribute value of the property. The statement `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Student();` can be replaced by `propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myStudent` i.e. you can modify the properties of an existing object.

Also, have a look at a similar question: [Change Attribute's parameter at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269/change-attributes-parameter-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I think a good option is to create an extension helper  for the control you need to use (TextBox etc) and if the IsReadOnly property is true (Editable(false)) then generate a disabled textbox.

Comment: Of course I can make it this way but I'd prefer a more general solution.