# Dynamically switch applicable DataContract at runtime?

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization, servicestack, datacontract

Can I turn data contract attributes off and on dynamically?  Essentially, I'd like two data contracts, one between the 3rd party and my app, and one between my app and my client - without having to manage two DTO classes. For example, consider MyDTO:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Lame/3rdParty/Inbound/Key")]
    public string MyCoolOutboundKey { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to deserialize the DTO with ServiceStack.Text:

```
MyDTO dto = "{\"Lame/3rdParty/Inbound/Key\":\"CoolValue\"}".FromJson<MyDTO>();
```

But, I'd like to serialize it so that this Assertion would be true:

```
Assert.AreEqual("{\"MyCoolOutboundKey\":\"CoolValue\"}",dto.ToJson());
```

The actual object in question has over hundred properties, so I'm hoping to avoid having to create a second class just to allow for outbound serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - it's pretty well established that [you cannot change attributes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10047350/149060).

An alternative that would create an end-run around the entire issue, would be to pre-process the incoming json, replacing the keys according to a map, i.e.:

```
Dictionary<String,String> map = new Dictionary<String,String>();
map.Add("Lame/3rdParty/Inbound/Key","MyCoolOutboundKey");

JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
JsonObject obj = jsonObject.Parse("{\"Lame/3rdParty/Inbound/Key\":\"CoolValue\"}");

foreach (var entry in obj)
{
    entry.Key = map[entry.Key];
    result[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
}

Assert.AreEqual("{\"MyCoolOutboundKey\":\"CoolValue\"}",result.ToJson());
```

This way the only data contract I'd require would be the one between my app and my app's clients.

Answer (score 2):

So, there is nothing wrong with your approach, but I think you are underestimating the power of `JsonObject`, it's kinda like LINQ to JSON.

I used it to get geo data from Google Maps and map it to a nice little DTO:

```
var jsonObj = jsonFromGoogleMaps.FromJson<JsonObject>();

return (
    from x in jsonObject.Get<JsonArrayObjects>("results")
    let geo = x.Get("geometry")
    let loc = geo.Get("location")
    return new Coords
    {
        Lat = x.Get<decimal>("lat"),
        Lng = x.Get<decimal>("lng"),
    }
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's a sweet example.  I like it.  However, given that I have over 100 properties, and not all of them need to be mapped to new keys (.i.e. a key like "Currency" is fine both ways, while "Open/Close" would have to be mapped) - I still prefer maintaining a map and replacing the keys.   That said, if you have links to good 'power of JsonObject' write-ups, please pass them along.  Yesterday was the first I encountered `JsonObject` and I'd like to find out more about how it can be best leveraged.