# How can I get and set the Range attribute min and max?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
[Range(-3, 3)]
public float range;
```

I want later in the code to do something like :

```
range.min = 2 
range.max = 20;
```

Or get

```
int min = range.min;
int max = range.max;
```

Comment: It is only an attribute ... it is only used to use a different drawer in the Editor ... you can't access it

Comment: @derHugo Well, technically you could. However there´s not much use in it as they won´t be read by the editor.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  yeah what I mean is that especially `range.min = 2` makes no sense as it will not change anything

Comment: attributes are usually some static data, that does not change during your process. Why do you think you need that? What is your **actual** goal?

Answer (score 4):

You [can't change an attribute's state at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046601/change-custom-attributes-parameter-at-runtime), but you can read it using reflection:

```
class YourClass
{
    [Range(-3, 3)]
    public float range;
}

var range = typeof(YourClass)
    .GetField(nameof(YourClass.range))
    .GetCustomAttribute<RangeAttribute>();

float min = range.min;
float max = range.max;
```

Based on: https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/RangeAttribute.cs

Comment: Afaik it is `min` and `max`

Comment: @derHugo `max` would be the same principle. I've updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: What I ment is afaik it is not called `Minimum` and `Maximum` but the fields are `min` and `max`

Comment: @derHugo No, that's not the case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=netcore-3.1#properties.

Comment: hm I was more thinking about the Unity adoption [`UnityEngine.RangeAttribute`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RangeAttribute.html) (see [Unity Decompiled / RangeAttribute.cs](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/RangeAttribute.cs)) since OP tagged Unity3D it is very likely OP is using the UnityEngine version ;)

Comment: derHugo the fastest unity ninja in town, yes, it is better this way thank you

Answer (score -1):

Can you change it to an object like below?

```
public class range
{
    private float _value;
    public range(int min, int max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }


    public float Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > Max || value < Min) throw new Exception("value out of 
               range.");
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public int Min { get; }

    public int Max { get; }

}
```

use it like;

```
rangeObj = new range(-3,3);
rangeObj.Min
rangeObj.Max
rangeObj.Value
```

Comment: your class should probably be `public` or at least `[Serializable]` otherwise it won't even show up in the Inspector

Comment: @derHugo - class should be public - I was thinking it is implicit. I will fix it.

Comment: it still needs to be `[Serializable]` though ;)

Comment: This won't compile. Attribute arguments bust be constant at compile time.

Comment: true that .. didn't even notice your are still using it as attribute. It also won't work as intended since Unity doesn't serialize any properties ... only fields.

Comment: @derHugo  - my bad missed that - I did not use VS to write that. See the edited version if that works.

Comment: Instead of an exception you should probably rather use `Mathf.Clamp` to force the value within the range .. also as said not sure if this is still what OP wants to achieve as this now doesn't use any special property drawer for the Inspector

Comment: @derHugo That is on the user's discretion, I will leave that handling on the user. Enforcing a value on error apart from null is not good practice.