# Programmatically set enum Description Attribute value

Tags: c#, .net, enums, attributes

I've got a enum decorated with a description to get a readable description:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  [Description("First Class")]
  FirstClass = 0,
  [Description("Second Class")]
  SecondClass = 1,
}
```

For some customers it would be helpful to show a different description -  Is there a way to change the description value during runtime? Like

```
MyEnum.SecondClass.Description = "New Class";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change values in Class Attribute at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374934/change-values-in-class-attribute-at-runtime) - Hope it will help

Comment: I cant see how you can change it runtime. Not unless you save the new value in a storage of some kind like a database...