# Choose between attributes at runtime

Tags: c#, wcf, attributes, custom-attributes

I have a service interface that requires different attributes in different situations. In short there are two options:

```
[DispatchByBodyElementBehavior]
public interface FooPortType
{
    [OperationContractAttribute(Action = "", ReplyAction = "*")]
    FooResponse GetResponse(FooRequest request);
}
```

and

```
public interface FooPortType
{
    [OperationContractAttribute(Action = "FooAction", ReplyAction = "*")]
    FooResponse GetResponse(FooRequest request);
}
```

I could distinguish between the two using compiler options, but I was wondering if there is some way to do this at runtime, for example based on an option in the config file.

Thanks.

**Update** I'm trying to solve this by changing the attributes at runtime, but ran into problems there, as well ([followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808141/changing-operationcontractattribute-action-doesnt-work)). I'll update this question as I find out more.

Comment: This is possible using reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269/change-attributes-parameter-at-runtime

It's a hack though.

Comment: You can write your own attribute and implement logic of which attribute to use in it depending for example on option in your config

Comment: Attributes are compile time constants. You _could_ use reflection to generate the interface at runtime, or simply use two different interfaces.